# RegularExpressionValidator: Do not allow en dash or em dash with EnableClientScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex

I want to restrict a Textbox so that the user isn't able to enter any em dash or en dash.

I tried the following regex for my RegularExpressionValidator:

1. `ValidationExpression="[^&#x2013;]+`
2. `ValidationExpression="[^\u2013]+`

If I'm using the first one, on the client (Chrome) the validator will be rendered as follows:

```
validationexpression="[^?]+"
```

So the – is replaced by a question mark?

Also the second attempt with the hex value didn't work although the rendering was correct `validationexpression="[^\u2013]+"` but the textbox wasn't validated on submit.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just use the literal characters `-` and `_`?

Comment: The literal character will be replaced by ?

Comment: Try `ValidationExpression="^[^\u2014\u2013]+$"`

Comment: no - didn't work. Maybe the regular expression validator handles the regex differently to plain old javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I now switched to a custom control with custom javascript - the following regex works fine with plain old javascript

`new RegExp('[\u2014\u2013]', 'gm')`

INFO: if you want to detect any dash, you could also use `\p{Pd}`. This also works with RegularExpressionValidator ;-)